# Items in StackPanel and columns

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm adding controls dynamically to the StackPanel but all of them are aligned vertically and the items overpass the limit of the Height and not all items are displaying.

Is possible to align the controls based on the height and put it in several columns depending the number and height of the items?

```
<ScrollViewer  Grid.Column="2" x:Name="DetailInfoScroll"  Margin="25,0,50,0" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollViewerStyle}" >
<StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="25,0,50,35" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="StkText">
</StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Adding the controls:

```
  foreach (var text in texts)
    {
            StkText.Children.Add(new TextBlock
            {
                Text = text,
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify,
                FontSize = 14,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 25)
            });

    }
```

Comment: GridView works like this and it is used in several of the sample projects that you can create from VisualStudio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you asking for is called WrapPanel. I hope I am not wrong. :)

Check those links out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using  VariableSizedWrapGrid

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227651.aspx